# How to perform method

Tags: c#, design-patterns, methods

I have class `Person`, two child classes `Staff` and `Student`, interface `IPerson`. Also I have a class `Database` and class `Gateway`. Class `Database` has

```
private string name = "username";
```

and method

```
public void getName() {return id;}
```

Both Staff and Student have getName() methods. I need to create request getName() from student and staff classes to database through gateway. Class Gateway has to check if method getName() was requested by `Staff` (`then return id`) or `Student` (`then return "Go away!"`). 
Can anyone please help me with that. I was thinking about using `Gateway` as an interface of `Database` class, but because I am only trying to learn C#, I don't really know how to do that. Or maybe there's a better way of doing this... Please help
Thanks

here's some code:

```
public class Staff : Person
  {


    public Staff() {}
    public Staff(string id): base(id) {}
    public override string getName()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public override void Update(object o)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(id + " notified that {1}", id, o.ToString()); 
    }
    public override void UpdateMessage(object p)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(id + " notified about new message in chat: {1}", id, p.ToString()); 
    }
  }
```

---

```
public class Student : Person
{
    public Student() {}
    public Student(string id): base(id) {}
    public override string getName()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public override void Update(object o) 
    {
     Console.WriteLine(id +"  notified that {1}", id, o.ToString());
    }
    public override void UpdateMessage(object p) 
    {
     Console.WriteLine("Message for " + id + "  {1}", id, p.ToString());
    }
}
```

---

```
 public abstract class Person : IPerson
{
    public string id;
    public Person() { }
    public abstract string getName();
    public Person(string i) { this.id = i; }
    public abstract void Update(Object o);
    public abstract void UpdateMessage(Object p);
}

public interface IPerson     
 {
   void Update(Object o);
   void UpdateMessage(Object p);
   string getName();
 }
```

---

```
 class database
 {
     public string username = "username";
     private string name =  "user details";
     private string grade = "user grade";

     public string getName(Object o)
     {
         if (o is Staff) { return name; }
         else { return "Go away!"; }
     }
     public string getgrade() { return grade; }
 }


 public class Gateway
   {
    public void DoSomethingWithPerson(IPerson person)
    {
        string iD = person.getName();
        if (person is Student)
        {
            return "go away!";
        }
        else if (person is Staff)
        {
            return name;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a somewhat convoluted question. So, first off, I'd like to point out a few style issues with your C#.

- Your `database` class is lowercase while the rest are cased consistently. Some methods are inconsistent (for example, you use idiomatic PascalCase for some methods, and camelCase or lowercase for others).
- `IPerson` actually has no purpose here because you can pass instances of `Staff` and `Student` around as a `Person` and use everything in basically the same way as now. In most cases, you'll want to choose either an interface or an abstract base class, not both.
- C# has a notion of "properties", which is basically a convenient syntax for getters and setters. This is preferred to public fields (as in `public string username` in your `database` class or your `public string id` in `Person`) because it allows you to keep the implementation of the backing field private. The syntax for this is `public string username { get; set; }` if you just want a default implementation. You can expand this to more complicated things. For example, maybe you want to ensure that the username is trimmed. (1)
- Minor nitpick, but typically `object` with lowercase o is used.
- You don't actually have to call `.ToString()` on objects in string formatting interpolation. (2)

(1)

```
private string m_username;
public string username {
    get { return m_username; }
    set { m_username = (value != null ? value.Trim() : value); }
}
```

(2) These lines are equivalent.

```
Console.WriteLine(id + " notified that {1}", id, o.ToString());
Console.WriteLine("{0} notified that {1}", id, o);
```

Now on to the problem. To me, it sounds like you want different behavior for different classes. With the way it's phrased, this sounds like an access/permissions issue. Depending on how your data store is set up (in this case, it looks like constants in the code, but you could easily do some kind of query), you could do something like...

```
[Flags]
public enum Permission {
    None = 0,
    GetName = 1
}

public abstract class Person {
    /* ... */
    public abstract Permission Permissions { get; }
}

public class Staff : Person {
    /* ... */
    public override Permission Permissions {
        get { return Permission.GetName; }
    }
}

public class Student : Person {
    /* ... */
    public override Permission Permissions {
        get { return Permission.None; }
    }
}

public class Database {
    /* ... */
    private Dictionary<string, string> NamesDatabase { get; set; }
    public string getName(string id) {
        // As a consequence of being managed by Gateway, assume that the caller has access
        return NamesDatabase[id];
    }
}

public class Gateway {
    public string DoSomethingWithPerson(Person person, string desiredNamePersonId) {
        if (person.Permissions.HasFlag(Permission.GetName)) {
            Database db = new Database();
            return db.getName(desiredNamePersonId);
        }
        return "go away!";
    }
}
```

Supposing we have a constructor for `Database` as such:

```
    public Database() {
        NamesDatabase = new Dictionary<string, string>(2);
        NamesDatabase["id1"] = "Student Amy";
        NamesDatabase["id2"] = "Staff Mary";
    }
```

And a `Main` as such:

```
    static void Main() {
        Gateway gate = new Gateway();
        Console.WriteLine("Student id1 looks up Staff id2: {0}", gate.DoSomethingWithPerson(new Student("id1"), "id2"));
        Console.WriteLine("Staff id2 looks up Student id1: {0}", gate.DoSomethingWithPerson(new Staff("id2"), "id1"));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

The output is:

```
 Student id1 looks up Staff id2: go away!
 Staff id2 looks up Student id1: Student Amy
```

Feel free to ask clarifying questions if any part is unclear or I'm way off the mark in my assessment.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure if this is what you need.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var gateway = new Gateway();
        Console.WriteLine(gateway.DoSomethingWithPerson(new Staff(1)));
        Console.WriteLine(gateway.DoSomethingWithPerson(new Student(1)));
    }

    public class Staff : Person
    {
        public Staff() { }
        public Staff(int id) : base(id) { }
        public override void Update(object o)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ID + " notified that {1}", ID, o);
        }
        public override void UpdateMessage(object p)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ID + " notified about new message in chat: {1}", ID, p);
        }
        public override string GetName()
        {
            return DataBase.GetName(ID);
        }
    }

    public class Student : Person
    {
        public Student() { }
        public Student(int id) : base(id) { }
        public override void Update(object o)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ID + "  notified that {1}", ID, o);
        }
        public override void UpdateMessage(object p)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Message for " + ID + "  {1}", ID, p);
        }

        public override string GetName()
        {
            return "Go Away!";
        }
    }

    public abstract class Person : IPerson
    {
        public int ID;
        protected Person() { DataBase = new DataBase(); }

        public abstract string GetName();

        protected Person(int i) { ID = i; DataBase = new DataBase(); }
        public abstract void Update(Object o);
        public abstract void UpdateMessage(Object p);

        public DataBase DataBase { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IPerson
    {
        void Update(Object o);
        void UpdateMessage(Object p);
        string GetName();
    }

    public class DataBase
    {
        public string USERNAME = "username";
        private const string Name = "user details";
        private const string Grade = "user grade";

        public string GetName(int id)
        {
            // you should perform get something.
            return Name;
        }

        public string GetGrade() { return Grade; }
    }

    //maybe call it facade
    public class Gateway
    {
        public string DoSomethingWithPerson(IPerson person)
        {
            return person.GetName();
        }
    }
```